# Selecting several days before specified date in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I've a DATE column with continuous dates in a data frame. 
I also data frame with list of public holidays.

How can I select (subset) some specified number of days before holiday? 
For example I want to select 7 days before each holiday.

Answer (score 0):

use `outer` as in:

```
 rng <- seq(-7, 7)

 DF[DF$dates %in% outer(holidays, rng, "+")]
```

or using `data.table`:

```
DT <- as.data.table(DF)
setkey(DT, dates)
DT[.(outer(holidays, rng, "+")), nomatch=0L]
```